# Determine sets A and B

Tags: borel-sets, multisets

I need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

The task is:
Determine sets A and B if valid:
$
A\cup B = \left\{x\in \mathbb{N} : x\le6 \right\}, A\cap B = \left\{x\in \mathbb{N} : x\le4 \right\}, \left\{4,6\right\} \not\subseteq A, \left\{5,6\right\} \not\subseteq B \setminus A.$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for $\not\subseteq$? You can use **\not\subseteq**

Comment: Yes, yes ! Thank you, a lot !!

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: So, $A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}, A\cap B=\{1,2,3,4\} \&\  hypothesis\ \implies 6\in A\backslash B, 5\in B\backslash A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $\{1,2,3,4\} = A \cap B$ and $\{1,2,3,4, 5, 6\} = A \cup B$. Therefore $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = \{5,6\}$. From $ \left\{4,6\right\} \not\subseteq A$, we deduce that $6 \notin A$ and $6 \in B$. And from $\left\{5,6\right\} \not\subseteq B \setminus A$ that $5 \in A$.

Finally $A = \{1,2,3,4, 5\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3,4, 6\}$.

Comment: Thank you, a lot ! :-)

Comment: I have one question :How is it that if 4 and 6 are not a subset of the set A, it holds that 4 is in the set A? I understand that 4 enters the cross section of the set, but shouldn't it follow from these two conditions that the problem has no solution?

Comment: $A$ is not a subset of $B$ means that it exists at least one element of $A$ that is not an element of $B$. This is the case here for $6 \notin A$.

Comment: A is not a subset of B, how did you conclude that?

Comment: It meant generally. Not referring to our specific $A,B$. Let's say $C$ is not a subset of $D$ means that it exists at least one element of $C$ that is not an element of $D$.